# Tornado google oauth error

Tags: python, oauth, tornado

I have the next problem with `tornado.oauth` : when user logs in with Google,Google sends me code to my redirect uri and then I try to get some information about user with the function `get_authenticated_user`

```
class GoogleOAuth2CodeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler,
                           tornado.auth.GoogleOAuth2Mixin):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        user =yield self.get_authenticated_user(
            redirect_uri='http://localhost:8890/userdata',
            code=self.get_argument("code")
        )
        self.write("hello world!")
```

but it fails with the next error:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception GET
KeyError: 'google_oauth'
```

Settings:

```
settings = dict(
        cookie_secret="32oETzKXQAGaYdkL5gEmGeJJFuYh7EQnp2XdTP1o/Vo=",
        login_url="/auth/login",
        redirect_uri="http://localhost:8890/auth",
        google_consumer_key="",
        google_consumer_secret="",
        google_permissions="https://mail.google.com/ https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
        google_permissions2="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    ))
```

`consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` are correct 
`authorize_redirect` works correctly and I really get correct google code

Answer (score 2):

`google_consumer_key` and `google_consumer_secret` are from the OAuth1 Google mixin. For oauth2, you need a `google_oauth` setting, which should be a dict containing 'key' and 'secret' fields:

```
  google_oauth={"key": CLIENT_ID, "secret": CLIENT_SECRET},
```

Comment: Note: You may not need to double close bracket.